# Project Tango C examples and area recording initialization

Tags: google-project-tango

The documentation for Project Tango Explorer states that it is vital to hold the unit steady before beginning area learning.  The C examples provided don't include this.  What exactly is the interaction here?  Does the device have to be stable prior to enabling area learning?  How do I determine when the device has been stable for a sufficient time period?

Answer (score 0):

I have the *impression* that holding the device steady **at the time you connect to the Tango service is the key point** - this is when the device and camera to IMU frames are getting set up -  I have determined that if you don't hold the device steady in the explorer app when asked to do so, it just keeps waiting until you do - it really is watching  :-)

I haven't seen any reference to the animation they use in the demo apps -  I would use it too if I had.

Comment: I was hoping for specifics.  Given a bit of information, we could possibly use the intent directly from Explorer.  But I was also hoping for specifics as to how area learning needs to be initialized vis-a-vis a stable platform.  A look at the logcat from Explorer only shows the MainActivity launch, so more into there is in order.

Comment: I hear you - but impressions and anecdotes are the best evidence we have for much right now  :-(